# I want to change a tuple into string without joining it in python. How could I do that?

Tags: python, string, tuples

For Example:
I want to change
t=('a', 'b', 'c')
to
s='a', 'b', 'c'

Comment: please decribe the output you expect, `s='a', 'b', 'c'` is not a valid statement in python

Comment: t and s both are same. Either we can write a tuple with parentheses or without.

Comment: you want to convert the tuple to a list?

Answer (score 1):

```
  t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
  s = 'a','b', 'c'
  print(s==t)
  # output True
```

if you want `s = 'a,b,c'` then you can do it by joining which you do not want to do. Also, it's useless to write `'a','b','c'` as string, however you can do that by using commented code. Please consider writing `s = a,b,c`

```
s = ''
for i in t:
    s += str(',') + i          # s += str(',') + str("'") + i + str("'")
s = s[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list that contains the letters:

```
t_modified=list(t)
```

output

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the output to be a string. You made a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=('a', 'b', 'c')
print(list(t))
['a', 'b', 'c']

",".join(list(t))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the output to be a string. You made a list.

Comment: the list can be joined

Comment: ...and the OP said "*without joining it in python*". You don't need to convert to a list to use join. I admit though the question is very unclear.