# Extract capital letters from tuples and lists

Tags: python, tuples

**Given Input:**

```
names = [("George", "Washington"), ("Thomas", "Jefferson"), ("Abraham","Lincoln")]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
['GW', 'TJ', 'AL']
```

==============================================

Capital letters should be extracted from the given information and printed `['GW', 'TJ', 'AL']`.

When I solved similar problems before, I converted the list value into a string at all.

After converting to a string, I intended to collect the return of the true value by turning `isupper` to the `for` statement.

After that, I was going to slice 2 pieces and put them in the list.

However, it is said that the same method cannot be used because the list and tuple are combined.

It says `.join()` is not available.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Please help me.

#I'm not good at English, so I'm changing it to a translator.

#English can be strange. I'm sorry.

Comment: Post your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Try: `[''.join((x[0], y[0])) for x,y in names]` . The solution will work if there are always exact two items in each tuple inside the list, and it's the first character always which is `upper`

Comment: Here examples of not using join to accomplish your task:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934897/i-want-to-change-a-tuple-into-string-without-joining-it-in-python-how-could-i-d

Answer (score 1):

```py
names = [("George", "Washington"), ("Thomas", "Jefferson"), ("Abraham","Lincoln")]

print(["".join([j for j in "".join(list(k)) if j.isupper()]) for k in names])
```

### Result

['GW', 'TJ', 'AL']

Answer (score 0):

You can write functions in a more pythonic way as below: -

1. ##### Using `map` function

   ```
    def convertStringWithMap(names):
        temp = list(map(lambda x: "".join(x), names))
        return list(map(lambda x: "".join(list(filter(lambda u: u.isupper(), x))), temp))
   print(convertStringWithMap(names))
   ```
2. ##### More pythonic solution using list comprehension: -

   ```
    def convertStringWithLC(names):
       temp = ["".join(x) for x in names]
       return ["".join([u for u in x if u.isupper()]) for x in temp]
   print(convertStringWithLC(names))
   ```

If I consider the input as `names = [("GeorGe", "WashiNgton"), ("ThoMas", "Jefferson"), ("Abraham","Lincoln")]` and pass it any of the function above, output will be as below: -

`['GGWN', 'TMJ', 'AL']`

you can further shorten the function using more `map()` or `list comprehension` objects but it will make the code a bit clumsy

Answer (score 0):

```
        names = [("George", "Washington"), ("Thomas", "Jefferson"), ("Abraham","Lincoln")]
        lis=[]
        for  i in names:
             k=""
             for j in i:
                k+=j[0]
             lis.append(k)
         print(lis)
```